# How to implement variable interest rates efficiently

Tags: solidity, contract-design

If a smart contract wants to pay interest on a balance of a user that's pretty much straight forward. You record the balance and the timestamp when a token was deposited and when the token is withdrawn you apply the interest rate on top of the balance using the current timestamp.

But what would be an efficient way to set different interest rates manually? Let's say the interest rate is 2% after a few months it's increased to 5% and after a while that it's lowered to 3% again. My current approach would be to have an array of timestamps/interest rates and when withdrawing I iterate through that array and apply the interest rates for these certain time periods. But I know that iterating through unbounded arrays should be avoided, as this could result in high gas usage over time and worst case lock all withdrawals due to running out of gas.

Is there another approach I could take to apply variable interest rates upon a withdrawal?

Comment: Whenever you change the interest rate (presumably there's a function call for that), you could have that function also calculate all the interest owed up to that point and add it to the balance. Then any withdrawal transaction only has to compute the final amount using a single interest rate.

Comment: This would consume a lot of gas similar to an airdrop wouldn't it?